# Is "will_paginate" supports client-side pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using `will_paginate` gem for pagination.

In some of my cases, the query will take almost a minute to respond back. In this, the `will_paginate` will send request to server to fetch(query) the data from DB for every page and it takes same time to respond.

Is it possible to make Client-Side Pagination via the `will_paginate gem`, which queries the DB a single time and paginates it on the client side.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support client side pagination, you can use some javascript lib.  but, you can also add some trigger class in "will_paginate" gem for ajax's style pagination. 
if you want pure client side pagination, you can google jquery pagination.

Comment: @xanderzhang- with that way also the query will be fire on the database and then the response will be affect on the user end.

Comment: Yes, why not try a pure javascript pagination lib?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @xanderzhang. Now I'm trying to achieve the pagination by using Javascript Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also load all of your data (without will_paginate) and use a suitable javascript library for paginating it like `datatables`. But, consider that if your data is large it would take too long time to load on the client side. It is suitable for low-size data.

You can find some samples here: https://www.datatables.net/.

This library is easy-to-use. Just add the following code to activate the library after adding it's `css` and `js` files:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```